# List Comprehension for DropdownButton in Flutter (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, list-comprehension

I am currently learning Flutter and want to create a `DropdownButton` with the following list:

```
const List<String> currenciesList = [
  'AUD',
  'BRL',
  'CAD',
  'CNY',
  'EUR',
];
```

The `item` attribute of the `DropdownButton` widget expects a list. Therefore, I want to clean the code by using a list comprehension. I have written the following function to create a `DropdownMenuItem` depending on the given string:

```
DropdownMenuItem makeDropdownMenuItem (String currency) {
  DropdownMenuItem item = DropdownMenuItem(
    child: Text(currency),
    value: currency,
  );
  return item;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I use the list comprehension syntax I found [here](https://pythonisrad.medium.com/list-comprehensions-in-dart-a57d3a06b703), I get an error:

```
child: DropdownButton<String>(
              value: selectedCurrency,
              items: currenciesList.map((currency) => makeDropdownMenuItem(currency)).toList(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedCurrency = value;
                });
            },
```

> type 'List<DropdownMenuItem>' is not a subtype of type
> 'List<DropdownMenuItem>?'

Can anyone help me fixing this please? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DropdownMenuItem](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownMenuItem-class.html) is a generic class, so you've to specify the actual type explicitly in your makeDropdownMenuItem function:

```dart
DropdownMenuItem<String> makeDropdownMenuItem(String currency) {
  final item = DropdownMenuItem(
    child: Text(currency),
    value: currency,
  );
  return item;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all,

> Unfortunately, when I use the list comprehension syntax I found, I get an error:

That's not the new list comprehension. This is:

```dart
child: DropdownButton<String>(
  value: selectedCurrency,
  onChanged: (value) => setState(() => selectedCurrency = value),
  items: [
    for (final currency in currenciesList)
      makeDropdownMenuItem(currency)
  ],
)
```

I find it much cleaner and you can add `if`s or nested `for` loops too.

---

Then, as @Midhun said, you need to mark your function as returning a `DropdownMenuItem<String>`. Or, you can continue using your list comprehension:

```dart
child: DropdownButton<String>(
  value: selectedCurrency,
  onChanged: (value) => setState(() => selectedCurrency = value),
  items: [
    for (final currency in currenciesList) DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text(currency),
      value: currency,
    );
  ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I try to use your syntax for list comprehension, I get an alert to update my SDK constraints. Do you know what that means?

Comment: Yes, the new collection-for syntax [was released in Dart 2.3](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-3-optimized-for-building-user-interfaces-e84919ca1dff), so you'll need to make sure your `pubspec.yaml` file requires a Dart version of at least 2.3 (and then run `flutter pub get`).